# Java code gets not executed

Tags: java, android

I developing android app and now I have problem. Below is a part of my code, and it keeps skipping the "for" part. When I put a breakpoint inside for statement, it stops at the point, and executes the lines very well and makes an output that I want. When I just 'run' app, it skips that part so "String locations" value doesn't change. I googled and some say it's thread-related problem. So I put synchroinzed on the method, still not working. Any other suggestions?

## UPDATE

I was trying to show code only related to the problem, but I think now showing the whole would be more useful for those who try to help so here's my entire code on showMapActivity. You can see I've tried some ways around and nothing worked. Saving path's information into String url is where I'm having problem. I tested, and other parts seem to work fine. I know my code is really massy, that was why I only posted parts of the code. TMap related classes are imported from .jar file.

```
public class showMapActivity extends Activity {


TMapData tmapdata=new TMapData();
TMapView tmapView;
TMapPoint origin, dest;
volatile ArrayList<TMapPoint> points=new ArrayList<>();
private TextView x;
private TextView y;
private HashMap<String,LatLng> coordinates;
private HashMap<LatLng,Double> finalpoint;

static private ConcurrentHashMap<Double,Double> path;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map);
    coordinates=new HashMap<>();
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    tmapView=new TMapView(this);
    path=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    coordinates=(HashMap<String,LatLng>)intent.getSerializableExtra("coordinate");
    path=getPathPoints(coordinates);
    int i=0;
    String url=getUrl();
    //String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=";
    //String locations="";
    /*
    Iterator<Double> keys= path.keySet().iterator();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        Double key=keys.next();
        //String lat=String.valueOf(key);
        //String lng=String.valueOf(path.get(key));
        locations=locations+String.valueOf(key)+","+String.valueOf(path.get(key));
        if(keys.hasNext())
            locations=locations+"|";
    }path.entrySet()

*/

    /*

    for(ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<Double,Double> elem : path.entrySet())
    {
        String lat=String.valueOf(elem.getKey());
        String lng=String.valueOf(elem.getValue());
        locations=locations+lat+","+lng;
        i++;
        if(i!=path.size())
        {
            locations=locations+"|";
        }
    }
    */

    //url=url+locations+"&key=AIzaSyDD88VFMPIfC5sr0XsFL0PDCE-QRN8gQto";

    //String url=getUrl(path);
    FetchUrl fetchUrl=new FetchUrl();
    fetchUrl.execute(url);

}
private ConcurrentHashMap<Double,Double> getPathPoints(HashMap<String,LatLng> coordinates)
{
    final ConcurrentHashMap<Double,Double> Path=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    tmapView.setSKPMapApiKey("6bb5b7f3-1274-3c5e-ba93-790aee876673");
    origin=new TMapPoint(coordinates.get("origin").latitude,coordinates.get("origin").longitude);
    dest=new TMapPoint(coordinates.get("dest").latitude,coordinates.get("dest").longitude);
    tmapdata.findPathData(origin, dest, new TMapData.FindPathDataListenerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFindPathData(TMapPolyLine polyLine) {
            points=polyLine.getLinePoint();
            for(TMapPoint point : points )
                Path.put(point.getLatitude(),point.getLongitude());

        }
    });
    return Path;
}
//ConcurrentHashMap<Double,Double> path
private synchronized String getUrl() {

    int i=0;
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=";
    String locations="";
    for(HashMap.Entry<Double,Double> elem : path.entrySet())
    {
        String lat=String.valueOf(elem.getKey());
        String lng=String.valueOf(elem.getValue());
        locations=locations+lat+","+lng;
        i++;
        if(i!=path.size())
        {
            locations=locations+"|";
        }
    }
    url=url+locations+"&key=AIzaSyDD88VFMPIfC5sr0XsFL0PDCE-QRN8gQto";

    //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=
    // 39.7391536,-104.9847034|36.455556,-116.866667&key=AIzaSyDD88VFMPIfC5sr0XsFL0PDCE-QRN8gQto
    // Output format


    return url;
}
private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            //downloadURL
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        //ParserTask
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        //읽은 데이터를 버퍼에 저장
        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Double>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Double> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        ArrayList<Double> altitude = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
            //DataParser class 호출
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

            // Starts parsing data
            altitude = parser.parse(jObject);
            Log.d("ParserTask","Getting Altitudes");
            Log.d("ParserTask",altitude.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return altitude;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Double> result) {
        finalpoint=new HashMap<>();
        LatLng latLng;
        int i=0;
        for(HashMap.Entry<Double,Double> elem : path.entrySet() )
        {
            latLng=new LatLng(elem.getKey(),elem.getValue());
            finalpoint.put(latLng,result.get(i++));
        }
        x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        x.setText(String.valueOf(finalpoint.get(coordinates.get("origin"))));
        y.setText(String.valueOf(finalpoint.get(coordinates.get("dest"))));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your method is outside of the class. Please edit again with the correct code

Comment: And you need an AsyncTask (or other thread related methods) in Android to do any networking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Apologies for posting this as an answer - I don't yet have the required reputation to comment)

Simply adding `synchronized` to a method doesn't necessarily guarantee thread safety.

How and when is `path` being populated?

**Update after additional information provided**

The problem seems to be that the path points are being generated asynchronously, and you are trying to use them before the generation process has finished (or perhaps even started). This happens because the `findPathData` simply starts the generation process and returns immediately (i.e. before the generation process has finished). In your code, you then go on and build the URL which is supposed to contain the point data immediately. At this point the background point generation process may not have finished, and may not have even started. As a result the point map may be empty or incomplete, and your URL will not be generated as you expect.

You need to find a way to wait until all of the path point data has been returned by the asynchronous processing before creating the URL. This looks like it could be very difficult, if not impossible, with the version of the `findPathData` method you are using, because it returns points via the callback one at a time and you may not know how many will be generated.

I had a quick look at the API for TMapData and it has a `findPathDataAll` method which seems to generate all the points and return them in a single callback call rather than one by one. If this is indeed what it does (sorry, I can't read Korean), you could use this method and then generate the URL from the callback, because when it's called you know that the generation process has been completed. If you do this, be careful to make sure that you're on the main thread before interacting with the UI or Activity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: static private ConcurrentHashMap<Double,Double> path; path is populated when activity starts. I updated my question with more info :-). Thanks you in advance!

Comment: That is simply the definition of the variable. Please tell us how and when you are initialising it and adding the data to it that you expect to be available for the `for` loop in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was updating and didn't expect such instant reply. TMap related classes are imported from .jar file. I think I saw this might be the problem on some web.. if so, should I make another class only dealing with classes form .jar?

Comment: Based on the code you posted, I think the issue is that the `Path` `ConcurrentHashMap` you create in `getPathPoints` is empty when it is returned from that method. T I imagine that the FindPathDataListenerCallback()

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit add. `TMapData`'s `findPathData` method looks to be asynchronous - that's why you provide a listener. The method call returns immediately and in the background (on another thread, I assume) some process finds the path data and returns it via the listener.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and great answer. Now I understand what's making a problem. So to my understanding, I should make getUrl method wait till findPathDataAll method is done. I'm not a professional here.. Can you suggest a way to do that? or code to use?

Comment: I really think that you should do this yourself now that you understand the issue :) However, as a hint, the easiest (although not necessarily the best) way forward might be to move building and fetching the URL into the `onFindPathDataAll` method of the `FindPathDataAllListenerCallback` instance you'll provide when calling `tmapData.findPathDataAll`. You will, of course, need to extract all of the points from the provided `Document` first.